# A natural question about convergence

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $u,u_k \in C^{0}(K)$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a compact set. Assume that $u_k \rightarrow u$ uniformly. Is these hypotheses sufficient to guarantee that
\begin{equation}
\mbox{med}(\{u_k>0\}) \rightarrow \mbox{med}(\{u>0\})
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\mbox{med}(\{u_k \ge0\}) \rightarrow \mbox{med}(\{u \ge 0\})?
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the definition of $\mbox{med}(\{u>0\})$?

Comment: This is the lebesgue measure.

Comment: What is the difference between the two lines separated by 'or'?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, where does this name for Lebesgue measure come from? I've seen many ways to denote it, but this is a first.

Comment: Sorry I am going to correct.

Comment: Try it out with $u=0$ and $u_k>0$ or $u_k<0$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Let $K=[-1,1]$ and
$$u_k(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{k} &\text{if } x\geq \frac12\\
\frac{2x}{k} &\text{if } \frac{-1}{2}<x<\frac12\\
\frac{-1}{k} &\text{if } x\leq \frac{-1}{2}\end{cases}$$
and note that $u_k\to 0$. We have $\mathrm{med}(\{u_k>0\})=1$ for all $k$ yet $\mathrm{med}(\{u>0\})=0$, and $\mathrm{med}(\{u_k\geq 0\})=1$ for all $k$ yet $\mathrm{med}(\{u\geq 0\})=2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true under the given hypotheses.

Take $u_k(x) = \frac{1}{k} \max(0, \frac{1}{2}-|x-\frac{1}{2}|)$. Clearly $u_k(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, so $u = 0$. Then $m\{x | u(x) > 0 \} = 0$, whereas $m\{x | u_k(x) > 0 \} = 1$.

Furthermore, by considering $v_k = -u_k, v=-u$ instead, we have $m\{x | v(x) \geq 0 \} = 1$, whereas $m\{x | v_k(x) \geq 0 \} = 0$.